# Judge an apex object is a class type not a specific class type

Tags: apex, object, type, instance, function

We can use `instanceof` keyword to verify an object is a specify object type, like Id, String, Integer, Datetime...

```java
Object str = 'aaa';
System.debug(str instanceof String) // true


public class FakeClass {}

Object classObj = new FakeClass();
System.debug(classObj instanceof FakeClass) // true
```

So what's the type of an Apex class? not a specific Apex class type.

How can I just verify the `classObj` is a class type not the specific `FakeClass` type?

```java
System.debug(classObj instanceof ApexClass) ?
System.debug(classObj instanceof System.ApexClass) ?
System.debug(classObj instanceof System.Type.ApexClass) ?
System.debug(classObj instanceof System.Type.Apex) ?
```

All of the above is wrong, how do you implement it?

Comment: This is confusing, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Raul Just want to know a class object is a class type or not, not a specific apex class, how do you implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have that level of reflection in Apex. You cannot inherently tell that an Object is a user-defined class. You can tell that:

```
public class FakeClass {}
Object classObj = new FakeClass();
Object fakeClassType = FakeClass.class;
System.assert(classObj instanceof FakeClass); // true
// System.assert(classObj instanceof Object); // trivially true, compile error
System.assert(fakeclasstype instanceof Type); // true
```

The so-called `classObj` is an instance of `FakeClass`, so it is both an `Object` (as all objects are), and a `FakeClass`. There is no other identity you can use to determine that it is a user-defined class, except to know it is a `FakeClass`.

As I demonstrated above, though, you can use its Type, which gives you the ability to call a no-arg constructor (e.g. `((Type)fakeclasstype).newInstance()`), but you have to pass in the Type, not an instance of the class.